# Python > Selenium + CSV: How to open links from list in .csv file, loop code, append data on csv?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping

Am currently building a scraper, managed to the code going, but need some coding assistance / tutorial recommendations for the following program:

> 1) A list of links in .csv format to open with webdriver
>
> 2) To run the same scraping code for all the links in the list
>
> 3) To append the output into a .csv file

The basic structure of the code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    import csv
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    driver = webdriver.Chrome

    #driver.get("...link from csv file..."), e.g. with open('links.csv', 'r') as file:   etc...
    time.sleep(5)

    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('data-xl')
    csvfile = "output.csv";

with open(csvfile, "w", newline="") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(["Reads", "Average Time Spent", "Impressions", "Read Time", "Likes", "Publication Shares", "Times Stacked", "Link-Outs"])
    column headers

driver.quit()
```

**The problems:**

> 1) How to open the .csv using Python Selenium, and go to links in succession, row by row (1, +1, +1...)
>
> 2) To loop code for all links visited at step (1) and, even with errors (e.g. "element not found" etc.), can proceed to the next item on the .csv
>
> 3) Create headers in .csv (note: code structure above is inaccurate)
>
> 4) Print output into .csv by way of appending, and without overlap

Any hints on how to achieve the steps mentioned above would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

First you have to edit `driver = webdriver.Chrome` to `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

and

Here is full code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

#link.csv below
# https://google.com
# https://google.com
# https://google.com

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

f = open('link.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
reader = csv.reader(f)
w = open('output.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="utf-8")
writer = csv.writer(w)

for line in reader:
    driver.get(line[0])
    time.sleep(5)
    elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@alt="Google"]')
    writer.writerow(
             ["Reads", "Average Time Spent", "Impressions", "Read Time", "Likes", "Publication Shares", "Times Stacked",
              "Link-Outs"])

f.close()
w.close()
```